# search substrings and replace them after analyzing

Tags: python

I've got multiple occurences of strings like this in my file:

```
%na^me%
%name^%
%^name%
....
```

I want to search every string like this in my file and replace it after analyzing the string.
For example

```
string `%^name%` will be replaced `Data`
string `%name^%` will be replaced with `DATA`
....
```

To find my substring I use this function with regex

```
re.findall('(?<=\%)(.*?)(?=\%)', data)
```

It finds substrings fine. But how to replace them?

*The solution I see is to create map and iterate over to replace everyoccurrence with some value.*

But is there a better way?

Comment: Something like `'''%nam^e%....%name^%.....%^name%.'''` will become `'''datA....DATA.....Data.'''` By the way - `data` is only the example - I pass parameters `data` and should ajust them appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following pattern , note that you need to escape `^` with `\`. and instead look-around you can use grouping Also you need to use `r` before your pattern if you want to python interpret you pattern as regex format :

```
>>> s="""%na^me%
... %name^%
... %^name%"""
>>> l= re.findall(r'%([a-zA-Z\^]+)%',s)
['na^me', 'name^', '^name']
```

and for replace the string you can use a dictionary like the following , and replace your pattern with `str.replace()`:

```
>>> d={'^name':'Data','name^':'DATA','na^me':'DAta'}
>>> for i in l :
...   s=s.replace(i,d[i])
... 
>>> s
'%DAta%\n%DATA%\n%Data%'
```

Comment: Erm...The question is not about optimizing regular expression. And what does `r` mean?

Comment: @user1432980 you want to replace but before that you have many problem with regex , check out the update , i'll update again

Comment: But well it just works. I don't know regex well so if it works - I'm content with it.

Comment: @user1432980 for replace the string you need `re.sub` but as you want to replace meany pattern you need to use a datastructure like dictionary

Comment: I see. So I should use dictionary after all.

Comment: @user1432980 ok. check out the edit , i will edit the answer again

Comment: Erm erm...But in the last case - `%` won't be replaced. So basically I need to adjust expression to `(%[a-zA-Z\^]+%)`?

Comment: @user1432980 yes , you need to put `%` inside grouping. `>>> re.findall(r'(%[a-zA-Z\^]+%)',s)
['%na^me%', '%name^%', '%^name%']`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to go for `re.findall`. Just `re.sub` would be fine.

```
>>> s = '''%na^me%
%name^%
%^name%'''
>>> m = re.sub(r'(?<=%)\^.*?(?=%)', r'Data', s)
>>> f = re.sub(r'(?<=%).*?\^(?=%)', r'DATA', m)
>>> print(f)
%na^me%
%DATA%
%Data%
```

Update:

```
>>> m = re.sub(r'(?<=%)\^.*?(?=%)', r'Data', s)
>>> f = re.sub(r'(?<=%).*?\^(?=%)', r'DATA', m)
>>> j = re.sub(r'(?<=%).*?.\^..*(?=%)', r'datA', f)
>>> print(j)
%datA%
%DATA%
%Data%
```

If you want to replace `%` also, you could try this,

```
>>> m = re.sub(r'%\^.*?%', r'Data', s)
>>> f = re.sub(r'%.*?\^%', r'DATA', m)
>>> j = re.sub(r'%.*?.\^..*%', r'datA', f)
>>> print(j)
datA
DATA
Data
```